# When should you register copyright for countries you don't live in?

Tags: copyright

From what advice I've read, it's a very good idea to register a copyright for the country where you live. However, when should you also register a copyright with other countries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends very much on the particular countries involved. Some countries do not have a system of copyright registration at all. Of those that do, the benefits vary.

In the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states), one cannot sue for infringement at all unless the copyright is first registered. One cannot obtain statutory damages, or legal fees as damages, unless the work is registered **before** the infringement starts, or no later than three months after publication. So if one thinks it is plausible that one will sue for infringement in a US court, it is a good idea to register early. In other countries, the benefits may be different and the value of registration not so clear.

Note that a plaintiff (usually the copyright owner or claimant) can normally choose what jurisdiction to file an infringement suit in. Suit can usually be brought in any country where the work has been published or distributed. So one can limit registration to countries where one is likely to bring a suit.